# Converting Feb 21, 2019 6:10 AM to mm/dd/yyyy in R

Tags: r, datetime-conversion

I am trying to convert my date from Feb 21, 2019 6:10 AM to mm/dd/yyyy format and have used `lubridate::mdy_hms()` like this:

```
d1=mdy_hms(data$`First Activity (America/New_York)`)
data$`First Activity (America/New_York)` <- date(d1)
```

Now this converts my date to mm/dd/yyyy format but the year is converted to 2020. I can't debug why is my year incrementing by 1.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what's going on without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Maybe you can post a sample of the strings that have this issue. I'm not sure why you're passing `d1` to `date`, when `mdy_hms` should have returned a datetime object already

Comment: yeah...actually was just trying to do something with the value and forgot to make change in the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use base-R function for this.

```r
as.Date(strptime("Feb 21, 2019 6:10 AM", "%b %d, %Y %H:%M %p"))
#> [1] "2019-02-21"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

For the exact output format that you required, you can wrap it with another `format` function

`format((strptime("Feb 21, 2019 6:10 AM", "%b %d, %Y %H:%M %p")),"%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: I just want to inform you that ``as.Date(strptime("Feb 21, 2019 6:10 AM", "%b %d, %Y %H:%M %p"))`` returns NA on my R.

Comment: @Gainz Maybe it's a locale issue. Check `Sys.getlocale('LC_TIME')` to see if you are running R with an English language date/time locale.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes I guess it is probably because of strptime() abbreviation using current locale. I was just wondering, thanks. Edit : Saw you edit, yes my R is not in the same locale, I wasn't sure strptime() was using the locale info tho.

Comment: Mine is `"en_US.UTF-8"` and the result is proper.

Comment: @Gainz `old_loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8"); <do whatever>; Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", old_loc)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes thank you. I actually don't want to change it at the moment since I'm currently not using english dates. Altough, I appreciate your answer.